# restoring oauth2 credentials for the adwords api from saved refreshtoken (java)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I'm writing a standalone application with accesses the Adwords API. The oauth2 authentication and authorization works fine.

My problem is that I want to save the refreshtoken in a textfile and use it directly the next time I run the app to restore my credentials. The refreshtoken should be valid for 14 days, so restoring the access credentials would very good.

I haven't found an example which works. Can someone help?

Comment: where exactly lies the problem? You can't retrieve the refreshtoken or you don't know how to use it for refreshing the access token?

Comment: I don't know how to use the refreshtoken string (which I can retrieve) to create a new credential object and to refresh the access token. Alwin

Answer (score 0):

The `refresh token` is not much different from the authorization tokens.
[OAuth2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) has several *flows* that can be used to get access to the servers. The common (and savest) *flow* is the so called **Authorization Code Flow** ([detailed info here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)).

There your application asks the *authorization server* for an `authorization code` the first time the user wants to use your application. The user will get that `authorization code` over the website when he logs in and grants your application access to the service. Your application sends this code to the *authorization server* in order to get the first `access token`(and with it the `refresh token`). It is the *same* server you need to send the `refresh token` to.

Now, I don't know exactly what the server's uri is in your case, but this would be an example of a *POST* request you can send the server:

```
 POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
 Host: accounts.google.com
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE&
 client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE&
 refresh_token=THE_REFRESH_TOKEN_HERE&
 grant_type=refresh_token
```

If the request is valid, the server will respond with a new `Access Token`. [Here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) you can find more informations about the specific requests you can make.

**Keep in mind that every token (access- and refresh tokens) have to be stored savely.** The best way to do this is to save it encrypted and when sending the tokens use only *POST* requests and *https*. But this wasn't your question.

I hope I could help you with this.